# AC current limiter in a circuit

Tags: current, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, signal-processing, current-limiting

I have the following schematic of a circuit using an AD8652 op-amp.

I need to limit the output current to 5mA.

If the output current is more then it should reduce the voltage. Can someone suggest a way to achieve this, or tell me which IC will be suitable for an AC current limiter?

[image]

Comment: This might be an XY problem in that your "solution" isn't (in fact) the best way to solve it. You should therefore reveal the bigger picture as to why you need to limit the output current.

Answer (score 1):

Please see:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flEoff.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit will make, that the same voltage is across Rsen as is across R1. The trick is: You can limit your output voltage across RSen with the help of a diode and therefore protect your downstream circuits. The additional RLimit does not affect the outputvoltage accross RSen in normal operation.

**NOTE:** This does provide a "Voltage-Output", not a current loop.